# lodash filter array of objects by array of exclude property values

Tags: javascript, lodash.js

I ran into a scenario, I'll simplify the data to user/project, where I needed to take values like:

```
users: [
  {name: 'bob', project: 1},
  {name: 'sam', project: 2},
  {name: 'ted', project: 3},
];
```

and given an array of project ids I wish to exclude such as

```
excludeProjects: [1,3];
```

I want to return [{name: 'sam', project: 2}];

I was able to do this with a custom filter function:

```
let usersNotInProject = _.filter(users, function(o) { 
    for (var i=0; i<excludeProjects.length; i++){
        if (excludeProjects[i]===o.project){
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
});
```

However, I believe I am missing some more elegant way to do this with lodash. Is a custom function really needed for this scenario?

Comment: Without lodash: `users.filter(user => !excludeProjects.includes(user.project))`

Comment: I would have given the same suggestion, but since the purpose was a "lodash" solution, i remained with lodash :)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can do it with filter:

```
let users = [
  {name: 'bob', project: 1},
  {name: 'sam', project: 2},
  {name: 'ted', project: 3},
];
let excludeProjects = [1,3];
_.filter(users, (v) => _.indexOf(excludeProjects, v.project) === -1) // assign it to some variable
// Returns [ { name: 'sam', project: 2 } ]
```

OR other way of doing it is suggested in comments, this is more elegant:

```
_.filter(users, (v) => !_.includes(excludeProjects, v.project));
// Returns [ { name: 'sam', project: 2 } ]
```

Comment: I would prefer to use the `includes` function. `_.filter(users, v => !_.includes(excludeProjects, v.project))`

Comment: Hey thanks for suggestion `_.includes` didnt occur to my mind then.

Comment: no need for lodash, ES6: `users.filter(v => !_.includes(excludeProjects, v.project))`

Comment: I would have answered it with ES6, but it could be his requirement to use `lodash`

Answer (score 2):

Use [`_.differenceWith()`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.5#differenceWith) to exclude the items:

```js
const users = [
  {name: 'bob', project: 1},
  {name: 'sam', project: 2},
  {name: 'ted', project: 3},
];
const excludeProjects = [1,3];

const result = _.differenceWith(users, excludeProjects, 
  ({ project }, id) => project === id
);

console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.5/lodash.min.js"></script>
```